# Using Aggregate and Infowindow in CartoDB

Tags: postgresql, carto, infowindow, aggregate

I'd like to use CartoDb to map historic  addresses of a city ([link to demo](http://cdb.io/1ha7lm5)). Individual addresses are mapped as points on the map. Detailed information for each address point should be displayed in the infowindow The geocoded addresses are stored like this:

```
NAME   PROFESSION ADDRESS ... (+ CartoDb fields like cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator)
Smith  shopkeeker grand-rue 10
Martin baker      grand-rue 11
Wagner grocery    grand-rue 11
```

As long as there is only one person living at an address, I get the desired infowindow by simply doing a *select* * *from* _table_name_. When two or more persons are associated with the same address I obviously would need some aggregate function in PostgreSQL.

I am experimenting with:

```
SELECT  address, string_agg(name || ', ' || profession, '; ' ORDER BY name, profession) FROM table_name group by address
```

I am running into two problems:

1. In order to map, CartoDb expects the columns 'cartodb_id' and 'the_geo_webmercator' to be included in the SELECT statement. When doing so, the result of the query is not grouped by 'address' in the desired way; instead the unique 'cartodb_id' is used for grouping. So, the following is not grouping according to 'address':

   ```
   SELECT  address, string_agg(name || ', ' || profession, '; ' ORDER BY name, profession), the_geo_webmercator, cartodb_id FROM table_name group by address, the_geo_webmercator, cartodb_id
   ```
2. The output of 'string_agg' is treated as one field in the design for the infowindow.

   ```
   Grand-rue 11
   Martin, baker; Wagner, grocery
   ```

What I would like to have, though, is a separate treatment of 'name' and 'profession' in the infowindow, like:

```
Grand-rue 11
1. Martin
   baker
2. Wagner
   grocery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the_geo_webmercator should be `the_geom_webmercator`, before that gets you.

The rest, you'll need a way to pull a single cartodb_id instead of trying to group them. A simple way is just to grab the min one, something like this, `Min(cartodb_id) cartodb_id`. So I would do,

```
SELECT  address, string_agg(name || ', ' || profession, '; ' ORDER BY name, profession),
        the_geom_webmercator, Min(cartodb_id) cartodb_id
FROM table_name 
group by address, the_geom_webmercator
```

I'm assuming that address is always the same giving a geom, so that should work.

Comment: This pulls the desired results, i.e. all names, professions per address. But then I can't map this in CartoDB ('Map interaction is disabled, select cartodb_id to enable it') and use the pulled information for an infowindow.

Comment: can you cut and paste the final sql you are running here? I've tested it and it works, with infowindows. I get the feeling your final version leaves something out from the above.

Comment: It works now! I am using: 'SELECT  strasse_heute, string_agg(familienname || ', ' || beruf, '<br>' ORDER BY familienname, beruf),
        the_geom_webmercator, Min(cartodb_id) cartodb_id
FROM vauban 
group by strasse_heute, the_geom_webmercator'. By using some basic HTML in string_agg I also can style the infowindow a bit.