# Multiple points at same location in CartoDB - how to make clickable?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create a simple map based on data from our website. Whenever someone wants to access a specific file, they have to fill out a form that includes their ZIP code and some other information. To display where we're getting requests from, I want to have a map with clickable dots, and a pop-up window that includes more detail about the requester. This is pretty straightforward with the "Simple points" wizard, except for when there are multiple requests from the same ZIP code. They all get geocoded to the same location and you can only click one of them. Is there any way to make this work in CartoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several existent responses that could be useful for you:

- Aggregating data in the infowindows for the points that overlap: [CartoDb - Aggregate and Infowindow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90578/cartodb-aggregate-and-infowindow)
- A very similar one, basically a duplicated of the one above: [CartoDB: Displaying multiple items at same address?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135769/cartodb-displaying-multiple-items-at-same-address)
- One more, that shares the ideas above: [Can I include data from multiple rows in CartoDB infowindow?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124940/can-i-include-data-from-multiple-rows-in-cartodb-infowindow)

Basically, you need to move all the data to a single point as a clicking event will be triggered over the point in the top. You can find the methods for aggregating the data in the questions above.

Comment: Thanks! The second suggestion worked for me. I was hoping there would be something along the lines of [Leaflet's marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), but this does the job for now.